# How to parse a properties file that uses array notation in Spring 3

Tags: spring, list, properties

I want to turn this properties file:

```
myproj.myprops.authorizedRoles[0]=ROLE_1
myproj.myprops.authorizedRoles[1]=ROLE_2
myproj.myprops.authorizedRoles[2]=ROLE_3
```

Into a Spring 3 bean I could use like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authorizedRoles")
private List<String> authorizedRoles
```

Only I'm not sure how to accomplish that...  Is there an annotation or a bean processor or something that could help me accomplish this task?

What I'm **NOT** looking for is a Spring Boot solution. I'm already aware that `@ConfigurationProperties` could solve this easily in a Spring Boot project, but I'm working with a legacy common project that must support BOTH Spring Boot and Spring 3 apps.

I'm also **NOT** looking for the standard solution of combining the properties into one property like the following...

I do **NOT** want my properties file to look like this:

```
myproj.myprops.authorizedRoles=ROLE_1,ROLE_2,ROLE_3
```

And I do **NOT** want to handle my properties in this manner:

```
@Value("#{'${myproj.myprops.authorizedRoles}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> authorizedRoles;
```

Again, **this is for a legacy Spring 3 project that needs to support BOTH Spring 3 AND Spring Boot apps**, so I'd like to keep with the standard array notation that the Spring Boot projects will be using, even though I can't use `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Value("${myproj.myprops.authorizedRoles}")
private List<String> authorizedRoles
```

To access the array properties